# Upload file to Google Team Drive

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've been scouring the internet for a few hours trying to figure out what is necessary to upload a file that will be contained within a Team Drive.

I've read most of the documentation, the only interesting bits / mention of team drives I found are here, but unfortunately there's no specifics: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-teamdrives 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-files

I'm using the .Net gapi nuget package (v3). Create a service like the following:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
var secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "...",
    ClientSecret = "...",
};
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scopes, Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None).Result;
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "...",
});
```

I have the Id of the Team Drive I'm targetting, and I can successfully retrieve the TeamDrive by the following code, but there are no interesting methods here for uploading:

```
var teamDrive = service.Teamdrives.Get(driveFolderId).Execute();
```

I've currently been trying to use the normal `CreateMediaUpload` way of creating a file.

```
File body = new File();
body.Name = name;
body.MimeType = "application/octet-stream";
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(body, stream, "text/plain");
request.Upload();
```

There's a few interesting properties on `File`, namely `Parents` and also `TeamDriveId`. When setting the `TeamDriveId` to the Team Drive Id, the file ends up in my personal drive in the root directory. When setting the parent to the Team Drive Id, I can't seem to find the file anywhere.

There are no errors thrown, and the result of `request.Upload()` indicates Success/Complete every time (even if the file doesn't show up). Where else should I be looking to set the parent team drive? There's no other interesting properties on `File`, `DriveService`, or `TeamDrive` so I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Have you tried setting parents to a folder on the team drive ?

Comment: I didn't test with a sub folder, no - but I'd assume that the file would do the same disappearing act if the `SupportsTeamDrives` is not set in the request. (I just found it, so will leave this here for others that may be searching)

Comment: If no parent is set it should go to root.  That being root of the current authenticated user.    Setting the parent to the teamDriveId probably wont work as I am not sure that's a directory Id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to setting to the parent to the team drive id, you must also set the `SupportsTeamDrives` property to true in the request.

The code would then look similar to the following (I've noted the important lines):

```
File body = new File();
body.Name = name;
body.MimeType = "application/octet-stream";
body.Parents = new List<string> { driveFolderId }; // <--------

FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(body, stream, "application/octet-stream");
request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;                 // <--------
request.Upload();
```

The key here is that the Team Drives permission scheme is completely different to the personal drive permission scheme, so you need to explicitly opt-in to it to prove you understand the differences.

An extra bit of info, if you want to list or search for files in a team drive, you must also specify `IncludeTeamDriveItems` and `Corpora` on the request (in addition to `SupportsTeamDrives`).

A Search might then look like this

```
var existingSearch = service.Files.List();
existingSearch.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
existingSearch.Q = $"'{driveFolderId}' in parents and name = '{name}'";
if (isFolderTeamDrive)
{
    existingSearch.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
    existingSearch.Corpora = "teamDrive";
    existingSearch.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
    existingSearch.TeamDriveId = driveFolderId;
}

var existingResponse = existingSearch.Execute();
```